# Button onClick Event Does not fire in Android

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener, settext

I have written the following code for an activity in the android:

```
import java.util.Date;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class Step1Activity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_step1);
    Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculate);
    calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {

        EditText fullname= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); // !!Breakpoint!!
        DatePicker birthdate= (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePickerDateofBirth);
        int test=birthdate.getYear();
        TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        result.setText(new Integer( lifepath).toString()+" "+new Integer(test).toString());

      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_step1, menu);
    return true;
  }

}
```

However, when I click on the calculateButton (which has the onclick event) it doesn't do anything.
The textview I have doesn't update at all.

I even put a breakpoint on the first line of onClick (in eclipse) and it never stops there.

And here is the layout of activity1 :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Your full name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Your date of birth:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePickerDateofBirth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCalculate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Calculate Now" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What could be wrong? 
What can I do to make sure I'm doing everything correctly ?

p.s. I don't know if this might be important, but I have opened this activity1 from a button click event on the MainActivity in this way:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_step1);
```

Obviously, the event of that button works just fine.

Thanks,

Comment: Try the [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Comment: can you show your xml layout code of Button here?

Comment: There is no difference between OnClickListener and View.OnClickListeneer, since the import includes the view.View.OnClickListener. , but I tried it anyway and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Have you import this

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Try this once

Put this 4 lines outside setOnClickListener

```
EditText fullname= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); // !!Breakpoint!!
DatePicker birthdate= (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePickerDateofBirth);
int test=birthdate.getYear();
final TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculate);
calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View v) {

    result.setText(new Integer( lifepath).toString()+" "+new Integer(test).toString());

  }
}
```

See this works in my code

```
 btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(WepwareActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I did as you said and I put the lines right before the onClick. (still inside the setOnClickListener() ) .
It didn't work.

Comment: Outside means before this line "calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()"  See I have edited my answer

Comment: You can never do that and you code doesn't even compile. The **result** TextView must be defined inside otherwise the object is not found.

Comment: Declare "final TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);" And this should work

Comment: Ok, I made the **result**,**lifepath** and **test** final and now it compiles. But the problem still stands. No update is happening.
I added a couple of lines to my first post about how this activity1 is called.

Comment: And why should I take them outside? Isn't this in OnCreate event?
That means after it is created, if someone types something in the field (which they actually do) it doesn't update those values. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Try to write @Override before "public void onClick(View v) {"

Comment: We are just declaring it outside. It doesn't mean that we can't change it values. We can change that.

Comment: That's strange. After I add the override, I get this error:
The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way -

1) View.OnClickListener

```
Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculate);
calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    EditText fullname= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); // !!Breakpoint!!
    DatePicker birthdate= (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePickerDateofBirth);
    int test=birthdate.getYear();
    TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    result.setText(new Integer( lifepath).toString()+" "+new Integer(test).toString());

  }
});
```

2) OnClickListener

```
Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculate);
calculateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

// outside of oncreate. This will automatically created when you're let implement the onclick listener to your activity
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {

    case R.id.buttonCalculate:

        EditText fullname= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); // !!Breakpoint!!
        DatePicker birthdate= (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePickerDateofBirth);
        int test=birthdate.getYear();
        TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        result.setText(new Integer( lifepath).toString()+" "+new Integer(test).toString());

    break;
    }
}
```

**Update**

```
package dummy.usage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DummyUsageActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.third);

        Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculate);
        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText fullname= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); // !!Breakpoint!!
            DatePicker birthdate= (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePickerDateofBirth);
            int test=birthdate.getYear();
            TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            String lifepath = fullname.getText().toString();
            result.setText(lifepath+" "+new Integer(test).toString());
          }
        });
    }
}
```

From your code. First i got an `NumberFormatException` I just removed the `new  Integer()` for your `lifepath`'s `TextView` And, it seems work fine. See below screen -

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: I tried both solutions, none of them seem to make any changes.

Comment: @AramAzhari After updated your question. It seems right. Just try to clean your project and restart your workspace once. I think this will work. And, Edit your question with full xml code. Means, post your full layout

Comment: try to create another activity from the first activity and then run the code on the second one. 
The click commands on the mainactivity works just fine as I mentioned on my first post. 

The problem is the second activity.
'setContentView(R.layout.activity_step1);'

Comment: This is my main activity that calls activity1. The button that has problem is in activity1, not in the main activity:
`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        Button startButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   public void onClick(View v) {
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_step1);
    
   }
  });
    }`